# update select where is taking forever mysql with UniqueID

Tags: php, mysql

Hoping someone can help me, this is taking forever and I need to speed it up:

```
SELECT Col2, Col3 FROM Table1 Where Col1 = Whats in Table1 Col1
UPDATE Table2 SET Col2, Col3 Where Col1 = Whats in Table2 Col1
```

the table I am updating and updating from have no indexes and are around 2.5 millions rows each.

The query is processing around 60 entries per second and will take way too long to finish. The code is below:

```
<?php
 //establish connection to my Database
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'info', 'connect') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('test') or die('Could not select database');
 set_time_limit(18000);

 //maintain logged in status
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logtest` (`loggedin`, `timesince`) VALUES ('1', NOW());");

 $shere=0;
 $sql = "SELECT UniqueID FROM temp WHERE LongDec IS NULL ORDER BY UniqueID DESC";
 $fcr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($frr=mysql_fetch_array($fcr)){
   $shere=$frr[0];
 }
 mysql_free_result($fcr);


 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT UniqueID, LocationNum FROM temp WHERE UniqueID >=" . $shere . ";";
 $fcr = mysql_query($sql);

 while($fcrow = mysql_fetch_array($fcr)){
   $sql = "SELECT LatDec, LongDec FROM lotest WHERE UniqueID=" . $fcrow[0] . " AND LocationNum=" . $fcrow[1] . ";";
     $frr = mysql_query($sql);
     $fr = mysql_fetch_array($frr);
     $sql = "UPDATE temp SET LatDec=" . $fr[0] . ", LongDec=" . $fr[1] . " WHERE UniqueID = " . $fcrow[0] . " AND LocationNum=" . $fcrow[1] . ";";
     mysql_query($sql);
     //echo $fcrow[0] . ": " . $fr[0] .  "<br>\n";
     mysql_free_result($frr);
}
 mysql_free_result($fcr);

 //Move data to pool
 mysql_query("TRUNCATE pool;");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO pool SELECT * FROM temp;");

 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: the first two query have no sense .. could you rewrite these  in a sql coherent sample ?

Comment: if you can explain what do you mean for "Whats in Table1 Col1"  could help  ... could be you mean  (select col1 from table1)?

Comment: Table1 Col1 and Table2 Col1 are both a uniqueID that is sometimes duplicated.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, switch everything over to `PDO` -- also, it might be useful to use prepared statements and useful variable names.

Comment: Secondly, since it appears your `temp` table is temporary, look into using the MEMORY storage engine

Comment: In your first query  (select)  at the top you are referring only to table1  .. not to table2 ..

Comment: it is called temp but it is a permanent table

Comment: I think the part that is hanging is: $sql = "SELECT LatDec, LongDec FROM lotest WHERE UniqueID=" . $fcrow[0] . " AND LocationNum=" . $fcrow[1] . ";";
     $frr = mysql_query($sql);
     $fr = mysql_fetch_array($frr);
     $sql = "UPDATE temp SET LatDec=" . $fr[0] . ", LongDec=" . $fr[1] . " WHERE UniqueID = " . $fcrow[0] . " AND LocationNum=" . $fcrow[1] . ";";

Comment: for now I will comment out //Move data to pool
 mysql_query("TRUNCATE pool;");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO pool SELECT * FROM temp;"); and test

Comment: It is still taking the same amount of time

Comment: Also this is Server version: 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log - (Ubuntu)

Comment: Is there a simple script to accomplish 

SELECT Col2, Col3 FROM Table1 Where UniqueID =  UniqueID from Table1 UniqueID
UPDATE Table2 SET Col2, Col3 Where UniqueID = UniqueID from Table2 UniqueID